# Can Rust's clippy do autocorrection / autofix?

Tags: rust, lint, rust-cargo, rust-clippy

Is it possible to run `cargo clippy` with an option so it will fix warnings automatically?

From the help message, it does not look like this option is supported at the moment.

Answer (score 27):

As of June 2021 the autofix capability has been stabilized, you can apply changes using the following command

```
cargo clippy --fix
```

Answer (score 14):

`cargo fix` can already apply some suggestions deriving from `rustc`'s errors and warnings.

In *nightly* builds you can use `cargo clippy --fix` to apply some suggestions from Clippy. In some older Rust versions, the syntax is reversed: `cargo fix --clippy`.

If you are using a stable version of the Rust toolchain, you can opt-in to use a nightly build for just one command, by using `+nightly` to override the toolchain:

```
cargo +nightly clippy --fix -Z unstable-options
```

Comment: doesn't work currently https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/pull/7533

Comment: `cargo-fix --clippy` has been removed. Work is underway to re-add it as `cargo-clippy --fix`: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust-clippy/pull/5363, but it is not yet merged.

Comment: First you need to install clippy nightly (`rustup component add clippy --toolchain nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu`), and after that run it with: `cargo +nightly clippy --fix -Z unstable-options`